# Howto retain checkbox selections in pageable gridpanel

Tags: user-interface, gwt, gxt

I have a use case that requires a data table that is pageable, has a checkbox selection per row, and needs to maintain the checkbox selections when paging.

The best solution I could find so far is:

http://blog.mersoft.com/2008/12/30/gwt-ext-retain-checkbox-selections-in-page-able-gridpanel/

Does anyone know a simpler solution?

Answer (score 2):

We subclassed CheckBoxSelectionModel to introduce this functionality (including global select-all/unselect-all support such that with select-all if you unselect one item, we only track the one unselected item and with unselect-all if you select one, we track just the one selected).

You'll have to override methods and deal with a lot of issues with refresh of the paging toolbar etc.

Comment: Khabram, we're now on this way of sorrow too, subclassing this LiveGrid checkbox stuff, so, can I ask you for you to give me this subclass?

Comment: Sure thing. Give me a day.